# Enviar e-mail com PHP contendo HTML

Tags: php, html, css, envio-de-email

Estou tentando desesperadamente enviar um email via PHP, conforme o código abaixo. Porém o código quebra quando insiro HTML, exemplo:

```
$mensagem = "<html> (...) </html>";
```

Vou precisar de uma página inteira ai dentro!
Já tentei também:

```
   // Abre o template...
   $corpoDoEmail = file_get_contents(index.txt');

   //E troca as variáveis
   $corpoDoEmail = str_replace( '%NOME%', $nome,       $corpoDoEmail );
```

Mas não funciona, não traz nenhum dado.

```
<?php

$para = "gabriel@.com.br";
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$assunto = "Ebah! Temos um novo usuário!";
$mensagem = "<strong>Nome:  </strong>".$nome;
$mensagem .= "<br><br>O usuário: ".$_POST['nome'];
$mensagem .= " quer receber nosso e-mail de Bem Vindo!";

QUERO O CONTEÚDO HTML AQUI

$headers =  "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";   
$headers .= "From:  Golleo<robo.wilson@.com.br>\n";
$headers .= "X-Sender:  <robo.wilson@.com.br>\n"; 
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP  v".phpversion()."\n";   
$headers .= "X-IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";   
$headers .= "Return-Path:  <gabriel@.com.br>\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, 
$headers);

?>
```

Comment: Recebe o e-mail sem nenhum conteúdo?

Comment: Eu recebo apenas o que eta declarado no "$mensagem", porém queria colocar uma página html inteiro, pro email ter um layout mais bonito!

Comment: Ahhh, você recebe o e-mail sem formatação

Comment: Na verdade eu quero mandar essa página inteira no e-mail: http://golleo.com.br/developer/workspace/golleosignupmail/index.html

Comment: @Gabriel remova o DOCTYPE e as tags html, head, meta, title, script e body. Alguns serviços de e-mail bloqueiam mensagens que contenham essas tags porque elas podem modificar o comportamento padrão do serviço de e-mail.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como pegar um formulário e mandar para o e-mail?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/342893/como-pegar-um-formul%c3%a1rio-e-mandar-para-o-e-mail)

Answer (score 0):

Tente trocar por esse Header

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Obs: troque o Header todo.

Notei um erro no seu código postado acima, esqueceu de colocar uma aspa.

```
// Abre o template...
$corpoDoEmail = file_get_contents(index.txt');
```

altere para

```
// Abre o template...
$corpoDoEmail = file_get_contents('index.txt');
```

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não!

Olha quero fazer algo assim: http://golleo.com.br/developer/workspace/golleosignupmail/mail.txt

Colocar a página em HTML pro PHP enviar

Comment: @Gabriel, editei a resposta da uma olhada

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, você pode utilizar a biblioteca phpmailer, a utilização é fácil e bem simplificada:

```
require_once("../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'seuemail@teste.com.br';
$email->FromName  = 'seunome';
$email->Subject   = 'assunto';
$email->msgHTML('<html>Mensagem HTML</html}>');
$email->AddAddress('destinatario@teste.com.br');

$email->send();
```

Esse exemplo tem o envio de mensagens HTML.

[PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)