# Enviar uma página html via email

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

To precisando de uma ajuda a respeito de como posso enviar o html de uma página via email. No caso, um cliente entraria em uma página e queira compartilhar essa tela com alguém, colocaria o email do fulano em um form e logo em seguida o fulano conseguiria ver a tela que foi enviada via email.

Comment: e qual a dúvida? pode colocar o código que esteja tendo problema pra ajudarmos?

Comment: Então, não tenho ideia de como fazer isso pois não tenho muito conhecimento ainda. O site que usa isso é o https://www.newage.tur.br/novo/?rv=20180508131346 clicando em Enviar para alguém, vc preenche um form e depois a pagina que vc esta é enviada para o remetente. Acredito que isso possa ser feito com o PHPMailer. Só pra deixar claro que eu não quero a resposta, quero apenas um norte. Grato pela colaboração.

Comment: então você deveria procurar um exemplo completo que atenderia melhor o seu caso. Tem até uma pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115048/enviar-e-mail-com-php-contendo-html?rq=1, e também essa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23602/como-enviar-e-mail-com-php e essa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/67012/dificuldades-no-envio-de-e-mail-usando-php

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, mas neste link trata-se de um simples email. Eu gostaria de enviar no corpo do email uma página html(No caso, a página em que o usuário se encontra quando enviou o form).

Comment: Então, o primeiro link que comentei mostra como mandar html no corpo do email: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115048/enviar-e-mail-com-php-contendo-html?rq=1

Comment: Tenha em mente que e-mails não trabalham muito bem com html, no sentido de que a formatação, css, etc. não ficará idêntica ao que é mostrado no browser, dependendo da complexidade da página pode até ficar bem quebrado mesmo o visual. Talvez fosse melhor capturar uma imagem da tela e enviar.