# Como pegar um formulário e mandar para o e-mail?

Tags: php, html, css, email

Preciso enviar um formulário a partir de um email, já pesquisei muita coisa, mas nada explica certinho o que cada linha faz, e se tem que ter algum servidor online, ou se com o local da para testar, vou deixar o meu html, aqui, se alguem poder me ajudar, ficarei grato!

```
<form  id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="enviarEmail.php">
  <table  width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <td  align="right">Nome:</td>
      <td><input  type="text" name="nome" id="nome" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  align="right">Assunto:</td>
      <td><input  type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  align="right">Mensagem:</td>
      <td><textarea  name="mensagem" id="mensagem" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Qual o código PHP que você está usando? Poste ele na pergunta e especifique exatamente qual é a sua dúvida em relação ao código, para que alguém possa ajudar.

Comment: Você está se contradizendo. `Como pegar um formulário e mandar para o e-mail` e `Preciso enviar um formulário a partir de um email`. Você quer `email -> form` ou `form -> email`??

Comment: Um formulario para o email, como se fosse um FALE CONOSCO

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<form  id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="enviarEmail.php">
  <table  width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <td  align="right">Nome:</td>
      <td><input  type="text" name="nome" id="nome" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  align="right">Assunto:</td>
      <td><input  type="text" name="assunto" id="assunto" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  align="right">Mensagem:</td>
      <td><textarea  name="mensagem" id="mensagem" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td  colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

SE FOR SO ESSE FORMULARIO: ta ai.

```
$para      = 'Fulanodela@mail.mail';
$assunto = $_POST['assunto'];
$mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
$cabecalho = 'From: email@quemenviou.mail' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: email@destinoresposta.mail';
mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $cabecalho);
```

### INFORMAÇÃO EXTRA:

VOCÊ PODE PERSONALIZAR, ESSE EMAIL CRIANDO UMA MENSAGEM PADRONIZADA. EU ACREDITO QUE VOCÊ SE INTERESSE NISSO.

```html
<input name="nome" value="RiscadoO">
<input name="sobrenome" value="RabiscadoOooo">
<input name="endereco" value="Onde judas perdeu botas">
```

```
//caputarando dados do formulario
$nome=$_POST['nome'];
$sobrenome=$_POST['sobrenome'];
$endereço=$_POST['endereço'];
$site="seusite";
$link_ativa=rand();
//final da captura
//passando dados para o email
    $para      = 'Fulanodela@mail.mail';
    $assunto = "ATIVAÇÃO DE CADASTRO NO SISTEMA";
    $mensagem =" Olá $nome !, você recebeu esse email por ter se cadastrado no $site , informações do cadastro <br> <b> Nome completo: </b> $nome $sobrenome <b><br> Endereço:<b> $endereço. <br><> Se estas informações estiverem corretas, copie o link: $site$$link_ativa. FIQUE BEM E OBRIGADO!;

    $cabecalho = 'From: email@quemenviou.mail' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: email@destinoresposta.mail';
    mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $cabecalho);
```

Assim vai ser sempre uma mensagem personalizada. claro que esse hand tem que estar gravado no banco de dados.

Comment: CARAMBA VLW MEU ME AJUDOU MUITOOO!!! VOU TESTAR

Comment: Se era isso que você queria, marque a resposta como aceita.

Answer (score 1):

tens 2 opçoes primeira mandar email directamente so com essa linha

```html
<form action="mailto:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
```

se quiseres em php dando o exemplo e só seguires (primeira lista e o php a segunda e o html do mesmo)

```css
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 
    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "you@yourdomain.com";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";
 
    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }
 
 
    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }
 
     
 
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required
 
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
 
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
 
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
 
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
 
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
 
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
 
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";
 
     
    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }
 
     
 
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";
 
// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
 
<!-- include your own success html here -->
 
Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.
 
<?php
 
}
?>
```

```html
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top"">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td valign="top">
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   <a href="http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php">Email Form</a>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Meu vlwww!, me ajudou muitooo!!